# Multiple Eloquent Where statements with multiple parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a parsing problem where I want to get all of the people with a particular subscription but not people who have another type of subscription. The subscriptions are stored in a comma delineated list in the subscriptions table in the subscriptions column. Here is the code I have so far:

```
        $includeQuery = [];
        foreach ($includeSegment as $include) {
            $singleQuery = ['subscriptions','like', '%'.$include.'%', 'or'];
            array_push($includeQuery, $singleQuery);
        }
        $excludeQuery = [];
        foreach ($excludeSegment as $exclude) {
            $singleQuery = ['subscriptions', 'not like', '%'.$exclude.'%', 'or'];
            array_push($excludeQuery, $singleQuery);
        }

        $included = Subscription::where($excludeQuery)->where($includeQuery)->get();
```

I get results back but some of them have the excluded subscriptions in them.

Comment: Using query functions inside where clauses helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with code above was in the boolean parameter I had "or" instead of "and". So only if all of the subscriptions for a particular user were present would the record get thrown out. Here is the updated code:

```
        $includeQuery = [];
        foreach ($includeSegment as $include) {
            $singleQuery = ['subscriptions','like', '%'.$include.'%', 'or'];
            array_push($includeQuery, $singleQuery);
        }
        $excludeQuery = [];
        foreach ($excludeSegment as $exclude) {
            $singleQuery = ['subscriptions', 'not like', '%'.$exclude.'%', 'and'];
            array_push($excludeQuery, $singleQuery);
        }

//        $included = Subscription::where($excludeQuery)->where($includeQuery)->get();
        $included = DB::table('subscriptions')
            ->join('app_users', 'app_users.customer_number', '=', 'subscriptions.customer_number')
            ->join('app_datas', 'app_datas.customer_number', '=', 'subscriptions.customer_number')
            ->where($includeQuery)
            ->where($excludeQuery)
            ->select('app_datas.device_token')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use whereIn and whereNotIn instead :

Subscription::whereIn($includeSegment)->whereNotIn($excludeSegment)->get();

then you dont need to also iterate segments once they are arrays of strings

Comment: ok, i just realized your column has comma seperated values, so this obviously wont work

Comment: then maybe you should try with whereRaw() and mysql LOCATE function, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate